# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\tanh x}{x^2}-\frac{\mathrm{sech}^2x}{x}\right)\frac{1}{\sinh x}dx$

Tags: integration

I am trying to integrate 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\tanh(x)}{x^2}-\frac{\mathrm{sech}^2(x)}{x}\right)\cdot \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sinh(x)}\tag1$$
and to simplify a little bit,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\tanh(x)}{x^2}\cdot \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sinh(x)}-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{sech}(x)}{x}\cdot \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sinh(x)}$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2\cosh(x)} \mathrm dx-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{x}\cdot \frac{\mathrm dx}{\cosh(x)\sinh(2x)}$$

I don't think I can use series here to help me.

Can anyone help to evaluate $(1)?$

Comment: I don’t think splitting the original integral into two integrals like that will be useful since the last two integrals don’t seem to converge.

Comment: The answer seems to be $\ln 2$ according to [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28%28tanh+x%29%2Fx%5E2+-+%28sech%5E2+x%29%2Fx%29%2F%28sinh+x%29+from+0+to+infinity).

Comment: Agree with @AlexMacedo ... writing a convergent integral as the difference of two divergent integrals is not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write
$$ I \equiv \int \limits_0^\infty \left[\frac{\tanh(x)}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x \cosh^2 (x)}\right] \, \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\sinh(x)} = \int \limits_0^\infty \left[\frac{1}{x^2 \cosh(x)} - \frac{1}{x \sinh(x)} + \frac{\sinh(x)}{x \cosh^2 (x)}\right] \, \mathrm{d} x $$
and integrate by parts to find
\begin{align}
I &= \left[\frac{1}{x} \left(1 - \frac{1}{\cosh(x)}\right)\right]_{x=0}^{x=\infty} + \int \limits_0^\infty \left[\frac{1}{x^2 \cosh(x)} - \frac{1}{x \sinh(x)} + \frac{1}{x^2}\left(1 - \frac{1}{\cosh(x)}\right)\right] \, \mathrm{d} x \\
&= \int \limits_0^\infty \left[\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x \sinh(x)} \right] \, \mathrm{d} x \, .
\end{align}
The remaining integral has already been evaluated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3274570/frullani-integral-int-0-infty-frac-textcschx-frac1xx-rm-dx) and in a comment to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2886236/a-nice-expression-for-int-0-pi-2-left-frac1x-sinx-frac1x2-ri) question (using Frullani integrals or the pole expansion of $\operatorname{csch}$) and we obtain $I = \ln(2)$.